# I am trying to run this command on terminal but shell returning find: missing argument to `-exec'

Tags: shell, unix

I am trying to run this on shell

```
find . -name 'node_modules' -exec cp -ra --parents \{\} /home/project/xwa/packages/custom
```

and i am getting `find: missing argument to` -exec'` , kindly help me .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You forgot the `;` argument (which needs to be escaped to prevent the shell from treating it as a shell command terminator).

```
find . -name 'node_modules' \ 
    -exec cp -ra --parents \{\} /home/project/xwa/packages/custom \;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using:

```
find . -name 'node_modules' -exec cp -ra --parents {} /home/project/xwa/packages/custom \;
```

You don't need to escape the curly brackets and you terminate it with \;